# RxJava hook not being called on custom Scheduler

Tags: java, rx-java

I have registered a hook via

```
RxJavaHooks.setOnScheduleAction(new MyOnScheduleAction());
```

and created a custom scheduler (for testing purposes) using

```
Scheduler scheduler = Schedulers.from(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor());
```

but the following piece of code doesn't call the registered hook:

```
Observable.create(subscriber -> {
    subscriber.onNext("Hi");
    subscriber.onComplete();
}).subscribeOn(scheduler).subscribe(myTestSubscriber);
```

If I, however, replace `subscribeOn(scheduler)` with `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` (or `subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())`, for that matter) the hook is called as expected.

Is this an expected behaviour? I'm using RxJava 1.1.8.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug with `Schedulers.from()` and will be fixed in 1.1.9. You can track the related issue/[pr here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/pull/4311).